# how to suppress ssl on a single controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `config.force_ssl = true` in my production.rb for a Ruby on Rails 5 app but need to have a single controller NOT force_ssl. Is this possible without configuring each controller? Is there a way to `unforce_ssl` within a single controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a secure controller:

```
class SecureController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl
end
```

Then you can make all controllers inherit SecureController

```
class ThingsController < SecureController
  ...
end
```

Except for the one in question. You'll have to make a one-time change to all controllers that you want this to apply to, but the good news is that you'll only have to do it once, and you then have the ability to extend functionality to SecureController. Sounds like your question is asking for a way to `:skip`, or `:except` on a `before_action`, but most Rails developers I know agree that this is the way it should be done.

Comment: thx - I ended up doing this way. I was thinking about doing it at middleware but I like this better.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this page](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods/force_ssl)

> You can pass any of the following options to affect the before_action
> callback
>
> only - The callback should be run only for this action
>
> except - The callback should be run for all actions except this action
>
> if - A symbol naming an instance method or a proc; the callback will be called only when it returns a true value.
>
> unless - A symbol naming an instance method or a proc; the callback will be called only when it returns a false value.

This is using the controller level force_ssl though.

The config level force_ssl, is application wide

Comment: This doesn't help. OP is looking for a way to exclude force_ssl for an entire controller, not just selective actions